# Mostrar Ocultar Menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo este header muy basico con un logo y un menu con dos imagenes uno de hamburger y una X para abrir y cerrar el menu, en mobile a la X le di un display none y al hamburger un block, ya lo tengo para verse en mobile y desktop, pero tengo un problema, en mobile el menu lo tengo oculto con un top -100%, con javascrip estoy haciendo que al dar click en el hamburger me cambie el top a 0 para mostrar el menu, de igual forma cambie el display de la X a block y el del hamburger a none para mostrar la X para cerrar el menu, el problema es que no se como hacer para ahora volver como estaba en un principio que es ocultar el menu y cambiar la X por la hamburger. Esto lo hago agregando clases en css y con un toggle agregarlas y quitarla, pero creo que hay una forma con if, para hacer esto, que es agregando unos estilos desde javascript, lo he intentado pero no encuentro la forma de hacerlo.

```js
let abrir = document.querySelector('.abrir');
let cerrar = document.querySelector('.cerrar');

abrir.addEventListener('click', abrirMenu);

function abrirMenu(){
    let menu = document.querySelector('.main ul');

    abrir.style.display = 'none'
    cerrar.style.display = 'block'


    if(menu){
        menu.style.top = '0px'
    }else if(menu.style.top = '0px'){
        menu.style.top = '-100%'
    }
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    background: rgb(228, 228, 228);
}

header{
    background: rgb(95, 95, 95);
}

header .content-header{
    width: 90%;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

header .content-header .logo h1{
    font-size: 25px;
    color: white;
}

header .content-header .hamburger{
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 9999999;
}

header .content-header .hamburger .abrir{
    display: block;
}

header .content-header .hamburger .cerrar{
    display: none;
}

header .content-header .main ul{
    position: absolute;
    background: rgb(180, 180, 180);
    width: 100%;
    right: 0;
    height: 100vh;


    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    transition: all 500ms;
    top: -100%;

}

header .content-header .main ul li{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 40px 0;
}

header .content-header .main ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 20px;
}

header .content-header .main ul li a:hover{
    color:rgb(255, 90, 90);
}

@media (min-width:768px){

    header .content-header{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    header .content-header .main ul{
        position: initial;
        flex-direction: row;
        height: 0;
    }

    header .content-header .main ul li{
        margin: 0 20px;
    }

    header .content-header .main ul li a{
        color: white;
        font-size: 18px;
    }

    header .content-header .hamburger{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<header>
        <div class="content-header">
            <div class="logo">
                <h1>Fron - End</h1>
            </div>


            <div class="main">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Nosotros</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ubicacion</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Informacion</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="hamburger">
                <img src="img/icon-hamburger.svg" class="abrir">
                <img src="img/icon-close.svg" class="cerrar">
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: Te sugiero de identes bien tu código y a la vez lo separes, css, html y javascript para que sea más fácil de leer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas 2 cosas:

1. Crear la variable del menú también fuera de las funciones, para no tener que declararla en ambas
2. Crear una función para revertir los cambios y asignarla al clic del botón cerrar

```js
// Carga todas las variables necesarias en contexto global
let menu = document.querySelector('.main ul');
let abrir = document.querySelector('.abrir');
let cerrar = document.querySelector('.cerrar');

// Asigna evento a los dos botones, con la función que corresponda
abrir.addEventListener('click', abrirMenu);
cerrar.addEventListener('click', cerrarMenu);

function abrirMenu() {
    abrir.style.display = 'none';
    cerrar.style.display = 'block';
    if(menu) {
        menu.style.top = '0px';
    } // No es necesario el else, porque siempre debes abrir el menú
}
// Revierte los cambios cuando se haga clic en el botón cerrar
function cerrarMenu() {
    abrir.style.display = 'block';
    cerrar.style.display = 'none';
    if(menu) {
        menu.style.top = '-100%';
    }
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    background: rgb(228, 228, 228);
}

header{
    background: rgb(95, 95, 95);
}

header .content-header{
    width: 90%;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

header .content-header .logo h1{
    font-size: 25px;
    color: white;
}

header .content-header .hamburger{
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 9999999;
}

header .content-header .hamburger .abrir{
    display: block;
}

header .content-header .hamburger .cerrar{
    display: none;
}

header .content-header .main ul{
    position: absolute;
    background: rgb(180, 180, 180);
    width: 100%;
    right: 0;
    height: 100vh;


    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    transition: all 500ms;
    top: -100%;

}

header .content-header .main ul li{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 40px 0;
}

header .content-header .main ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 20px;
}

header .content-header .main ul li a:hover{
    color:rgb(255, 90, 90);
}

@media (min-width:768px){

    header .content-header{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    header .content-header .main ul{
        position: initial;
        flex-direction: row;
        height: 0;
    }

    header .content-header .main ul li{
        margin: 0 20px;
    }

    header .content-header .main ul li a{
        color: white;
        font-size: 18px;
    }

    header .content-header .hamburger{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<header>
        <div class="content-header">
            <div class="logo">
                <h1>Fron - End</h1>
            </div>


            <div class="main">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Nosotros</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ubicacion</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Informacion</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="hamburger">
                <img src="img/icon-hamburger.svg" class="abrir">
                <img src="img/icon-close.svg" class="cerrar">
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 1):

creo que con algo asi puede funcionar:

```
let abrir = document.querySelector('.abrir');
let cerrar = document.querySelector('.cerrar');
let estadoBoton = false;

abrir.addEventListener('click', abrirMenu);

function abrirMenu(){
    let menu = document.querySelector('.main ul');
     if(estadoBoton == false){
    abrir.style.display = 'none'
    cerrar.style.display = 'block'
    estado=true;} else {
    abrir.style.display = 'block'
    cerrar.style.display = 'none'
    estadoBoton = false;}


    if(menu){
        menu.style.top = '0px'
    }else if(menu.style.top = '0px'){
        menu.style.top = '-100%'
    }
}
```